# Macbook Pro 2012 md101 gpu throttling

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, temperature

When playing games on Macbook Pro 13 inch 2012 md101 under Windows 8.1 the temperature rises to 100 degrees pretty fast and gpu starts throttling giving a huge slowdown in games. Is this a normal behaviour of this Macbook? If not what should I do to fix this?

This notebook has Core i5-3210M and Intel HD Graphics 4000

I was thinking about changing termal paste.

[image: gpu-z showing throttling]

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is perfectly normal behaviour. You can change the thermal paste if you want but you won't see any great difference in thermal levels. The Intel HD4000 GPU is integrated in the i5 die and CPU/GPU throttling is the main protection mechanism for thermal limiting .

Comment: is such overheating a normal behaviour of this macbook?

Comment: That's pretty hot but within the thermal limits. Given the GPU and CPU share the same silicon, it's going to get pretty toasty when given a fairly hefty workload. Bear in mind a dedicated GPU in a well-ventilated desktop will easily hit 60-70 degrees in a short space of time with a heavy graphics workload. The MacBook's cooling system is considerably smaller than that of a decent desktop card so higher temps are to be expected. Try turning down the available graphics options and see where you go from there.